# Yarn workspaces best practice when using shared library

Tags: lerna, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I have a common (or not so coomon) scenario for `yarn workspaces` and didn't find the right guide for me online.

yarn workspaces look like that:

```
 - monorepo
   - packages
     - client
     - admin
     - theme
     - lib
```

1. **Client** is used as our endusers, it is a react project
2. **Admin** is used as backoffice for admin users and it is build in react too
3. **Theme** is used for all the UI kit (components) and storybook. We use the UI kit in `client` and `admin` 
   project and this is classic "monorepo style" (lerna) to share components between 2 projects. This folder should be shared only for this project.
4. **Lib** is used for all API and shared "Business logic" between multiple projects. I have 4 project which use the same lib functionality for API requests, Authentication, Redux and more.

Additional information:

- `monorepo` is root repository with `.gitmodules`
- Each sub folder is a different git repository
- We use workspaces in order to have easy development on `theme` and on the `client` and `admin` project on the same time.

Questions:

We run `yarn start` only in `client` project and `admin` project. Both projects are using the same `theme` and same `lib` functionality. Because the `lib` is shared with other projects, it is updated on a weekly base:

1. How I can prevent from it to be updated from project to project? should I work with `tags` in git repository or should I remove `lib` from the monorepo worksapce and to work with it as `npm package` (the whole point is to have easy development process when we change the `lib` file we do not need to `npm update` it again and again.
2. If `lib` will be npm package, How can I tell monorepo to use workspaces when I run `yarn start` and to use the npm version when I run `yarn build`?

Please advice on the best practices for this scenario.

Thanks in advance,
Leo.

Comment: Did you refer this link: 
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/07/yarn-workspaces-organize-project-codebase-pro/
https://www.toptal.com/front-end/guide-to-monorepos
If you don't then please refer those links they have good suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FINAL ANSWER:**
I found the best solution *for me* and I tried it for 6 weeks during development (best practice).

I ended up with this structure:

- monorepo // git MAIN repository

  - packages

    - client // git sub repository
    - admin // git sub repository
    - theme // git sub repository
    - lib // git sub repository

The `client` and `admin` use the `theme` as `yarn workspaces` https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/workspaces/

`lib` is used as Git npm package with `git+ssh://git@gitlab.com:xxxx/xxx/lib.git#v1.0.1`

The main/sub repositories structure gives me the ability the manage version control for each project separately and on the same time to use shared "theme" (workspaces) and "lib" core (npm) by versions.

**Tip:**
For easy development I recommend to add the `lib` as `yarn workspace` because when we run `yarn start` it hot reload the changes in real time. When we do `yarn build` we use the lib as npm package with an ssh link.

Good luck!
Leo.

Comment: I doubt git submodule is a good solution in general.
I think it would make workflow cumbersome and may invalidate some benefits of monorepo itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my personal preferences.

```
- monorepo
   - packages
     - client
     - admin
     - core
```

I think lib can be moved to core, and theme are more like npm package to me.

Comment: Do you mean that Theme and Lib should be npm packages inside core repository?

Comment: The "Theme" is relevant ONLY to this project and the "Lib" is relevant for many projects...