# Submodules as yarn workspaces

Tags: node.js, git, architecture, git-submodules, yarn-workspaces

I've read that workspace packages should not be git submodules ([source1](https://dev.to/liyachun/javascript-monorepo-by-lerna-with-yarn-workspaces-and-git-submodules-4189), [source2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61119505/yarn-workspaces-best-practice-when-using-shared-library#comment117850178_62459309)).

e.g. this setup restricts the content of `packages`

```
root
├── packages
│   ├── package1 # a yarn workspace - should not be a git submodule
│   ├── package2 # a yarn workspace - should not be a git submodule
│   └── package3 # a yarn workspace - should not be a git submodule
```

Can anyone explain why workspaces should not be git submodules? It seems like a reasonable solution to me when I have one central `integration` repo that needs to pull in various other repositories that will share node_modules if they are setup as workspaces.

An `integration` dev repo would then simply be a top level framework that contains lint settings, a dev docker, etc. It would always have the latest working submodules pinned to it via commits.

Comment: It seems that links you provided talk about learna workspaces. Do they exactly correspond to yarn workspaces though?

Comment: They don't exactly, no. I don't think yarn workspaces were a thing when lerna was created and now it's no longer maintained.

Comment: It seems impossible. We keep two parts of one puzzle in different parts. It does not allow to install environment without parent package.json

Comment: I've been using submodules as workspaces for some time now and it works. The top level package.json is only used to specify the workspaces. The package.json in each workspace specifies the dependencies of that workspace. Therefore submodules can be cloned and setup individually or cloned and setup as part of the workspace.

Comment: @forgetso when you execute yarn install in the root directory of your workspace where all your submodules reside, do the git submodules install correctly? Do your git submodules have yarn.lock file in them? We have a same situation, although in our submodule we have yarn.lock file due to which the node_modules in the submodule do not install correctly and we need to yarn install in submodules separately. Now if we remove the yarn.lock from submodules, it works like a charm.

Comment: @BhushanPatil you need to remove the yarn.lock files from the submodules, if I remember correctly. This is a required manual step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using submodules as workspaces is an ok thing to do, both with yarn and npm workspaces.